# resignFirstResponder does not hide the keyboard

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

I was trying to include a UITextField inside a UIAlertView with the following code:

```
UIAlertView *newLabel = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"New Label" message:@"\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
UITextField *newLabelNameField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.5, 25.0)];
newLabelNameField.placeholder = @"Label Name";
[newLabelNameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[newLabelNameField resignFirstResponder];
[newLabel addSubview:newLabelNameField];
[newLabel show];
```

The main problem I am facing is that the `resignFirstResponder` is not working, that is the keyboard is not hiding when the return key is pressed.
Secondly is there any way we can write a method that has to be executed when the `OK` button is pressed, like say adding the `Label Name` received using the text field to a database. The method has to be executed only if we press the `OK` button, not the `Cancel` button.

Comment: Not an Xcode question. ---- "resignFirstResponder is not working, that is the keyboard is not hiding when the return key is pressed." - no, that's two different problems. You have to implement the appropriate delegate method (`textFieldShouldReturn:`) to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) For second question, First set some tag to the `UIAlertView` like `newLabel.tag = 5`;

2) Then write the following delegate method of `UIAlertView` by checking `tag` & `buttonindex`.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 5 && buttonIndex == 1)//OK button clicked
    {
        //Write code 
    }
}
```

3) For First question, write the delegate method of `UITextField` like

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not you are using default textfield in UIAlertview try once like this,

```
    UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" message:@"Please Enter the Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [alertView show];
```

EDIT:you'l get data here

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
       NSLog(%@"[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]");
    return  ([[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] length]>0)?YES:NO;

}
```

Comment: how to get the text that is entered into the textfield thus generated?

Comment: @Harikrishnan T:once check my answer.